# Insides of my house are not visible when I tap play button (P) in blender game engine

Tags: materials, game-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

In the object mode, I can see clearly inside my house. But in play mode, I can't see inside it. I am attaching screenshots. Please help. I am new to blender.
In object mode, I can see clearly backface which is in red.

But when I press P button, it seems like there is no base and backside! Please help with it :(

[image: In object mode, I can see clearly backface which is in red.]

[image: But when I press P button, it seems like there is no base and backside! Please help with it :(]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the material tab, and under the heading 'Game Settings' there will be a 'Backface Culling' checkbox, which should be checked. Uncheck that and you should be good to go.